# negative lookbehind regex followed by optional whitespaces

Tags: ruby, regex

Can't make it work in Ruby: 
I need to process some CSS and replace `}` with `!important }` if it has no `!important` already.
For this, my replacement looks like:

```
".a { zxcv: -90px !important; }".gsub(/(?<!!important;)\s*}/, ' !important;}')
```

which apparently should search for `\s*}` that is not preceded by `!important;`

It works only if I don't use `\s*` part, otherwise it ignores my negative check.
I know that variable-length lookbehind isn't supported, but I don't use it here. 
How can `\s*` spoil my regex in this case?

Comment: Do you want to replace with `!important }` or with `!important;}'`?

Comment: What do you mean by "works"?

Comment: I mean, if I remove spaces before } and remove white-space wildcard, this regex does the job then. 
It's not that important if it'll be with or without ; in the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have another lookbehind like this for matching:

```
input.gsub(/(?<!!important; )(?<!!important;)\s*}/, ' !important;}')
```

- [Rubular Demo](http://rubular.com/r/hEmazjH9Gm)
- [RegEx-101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gB8lZ6/4)

Comment: and for two/three/four spaces or a tab?

Comment: Yes it works with `.a { zxcv: -90px;     }` also in input, did you test? I've also updated it slightly to compress multiple spaces before `}` into one.

Comment: ok, I see now. I've only been looking at the regex here, not in tests.

Comment: Done. You'd probably want to edit the answer itself, not just the demos.